# Python Bokeh Google Maps Location History: multiline() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'xs' and 'ys'

Tags: python, google-maps, bokeh

I have written a script which can use the location history from Google and plot this on a hmtl website:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap

#place your history file in your project deirectory
with open("Standortverlauf.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print("JSON Load Successfull!")

lats = []
longs = []

#retrieving the lats and longs
for entry in data["locations"]:
    ts = int(entry["timestampMs"][:10])
    time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
    # place your start date as unix timestamp below
    if int(entry["timestampMs"][:10]) > 1554336000:
        lats.append(entry["latitudeE7"]/(10**7))
        longs.append(entry["longitudeE7"]/(10**7))

print(len(lats))
output_file("gmap.html")

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.81, lng=-122.45, map_type="roadmap", zoom=12)

# For GMaps to function, Google requires you obtain and enable an API key:
#     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
# or: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=hybrid-zephyr-271316 "Anmeldedaten", "Anmeldedaten erstellen", "API-Schlüssel erstellen"
# Replace the value below with your personal API key
p = gmap("API key", map_options, title="Location History",
         tools = "box_zoom, pan, wheel_zoom", width=1500, height=700)

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(lat=lats,
              lon=longs)
)

# change color and size of the dots below
p.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=6, fill_color="red", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)
#This adds lines but can take much longer
p.multi_line(x='lon', y='lat', source=source, color='red', line_width=3)
show(p)
```

The code works fine apart from the multi_line line which leads to following error:

```
JSON Load Successfull!
6373
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d49b67550055> in <module>
     48 p.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=6, fill_color="red", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)
     49 #This adds lines but can take much longer
---> 50 p.multi_line(x='lon', y='lat', source=source, color='red', line_width=3)
     51 show(p)

TypeError: multiline() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'xs' and 'ys'
```

Can you help me how I could debug the line and have connecting lines between my points?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just as the error says, `multi_line` accepts not `x` and `y` but `xs` and `ys`: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/multi_line.html#bokeh.models.glyphs.MultiLine.xs

Comment: Also, maybe you wanted a regular `line` instead of `multi_line`.